# networkBoundResource depending only with Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i´m developing a netboundBoundResource library based on the Google´s documentation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide.

My code looks like this (and it works ):

```
inline fun <ResultType, RequestType> networkBoundResource(
    crossinline loadFromDb: () -> Flow<ResultType>,
    crossinline netWorkRequest: suspend () -> Response<RequestType>,
    crossinline saveCall: suspend (Response<RequestType>) -> Unit
): Flow<Resource<ResultType>> = flow {
    emit(Resource.Loading(loadFromDb().firstOrNull()))
    val netWorkResponse = netWorkRequest()
    emitAll(
        if (netWorkResponse.isSuccessful) {
            saveCall(netWorkResponse)
            loadFromDb().map { Resource.Success(it) }
        } else {
            loadFromDb().map { Resource.Error("Error", it) }
        }
    )
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

where  looks like this:

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
}
```

I want to make sure that this library will work ONLY with ROOM, and I'm not sure how to manage that (it's working now with ROOM ). So, if a user in the user wants to use this library, let's say with REALM, he won't be able.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end this was a tricky one. I figured out that the flowOn was doing what I need it.